# parsing image in a wp7 app from xml

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

i'm 
following this tutorial : http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Employees_app_with_XML_parsing_and_messaging_in_WP7

I have this application that shows events in my city, every event got an image and a title and if I click an event I'll go to the detail page that show me the larger image, the title and the description of the event, everything similar to the tutorial and in fact it works pretty fine, the problem? it shows me only one event.

here you can see the feed that i use:

http://th05.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/f/2012/226/0/7/xml_by_javabak-d5b1d16.png

this is my Events class:

```
namespace Bluey
{
   [XmlRoot("rss")]
   public class Eventi
   {
       [XmlArray("channel")]
       [XmlArrayItem("item")]
        public ObservableCollection<Evento> Collect { get; set; }
   }
}
```

and this is my Event class

```
namespace Bluey
{
  public class Evento
  {
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("enclosure")]
    public string image { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string description { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I've noticed that in the event class if i change the [XmlElement("enclosure")] to [XmlElement("url")] I'll get all the events but no images

this is my parser

```
  public EventiPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // is there network connection available
        if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No network connection available!");
            return;
        }
        // start loading XML-data
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.applinesrl.com/appoggio/events/feed", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(EventiDownloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

    }

    void EventiDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
        }
        else
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Eventi));
            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
            Eventi eventi = (Eventi)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
            EventiList.ItemsSource = eventi.Collect; 
        }
    }
```

any help would be apreciated, tnx in advice!

Diego.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample XML you posted, it seems that your images are embedded inside the enclosure node. So, the Evento class is partially correct. All you have to do is something like that:

```
public class Enclosure
{
    [XmlElement("url")]
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Evento
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("enclosure")]
    public Enclosure image { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATED TO SHOW HOW TO ACCESS IMAGE URL:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Eventi));
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
Eventi eventi = (Eventi)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
foreach (Evento obj in eventi.Collect)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Title: {0}", obj.title);
    Debug.WriteLine("Img: {0}", obj.image.url); // Retrieving image URL
}
```

Note: some of the values in the XML are already images encoded in base64 while others are URLs. So, you should verify for those. Please find attached an image capture of the data i get with my code and your xml data. [image]

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your suggestion but it threw an exception while parsing the xml at this line                                        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result); I'm now looking for a solution for this enclosure nesting :/

Comment: ok my fault, while trying I changed the feed looking for a quicker solution and I forgot to return to the old feed getting the exception...I'm so sorry (it's about 5 hours that I'm on it and I start makeing very stupid errors), anyway your advice returned me the whole feed except for the image

Comment: I am not sure how you are implementing the code. But, you understand that now the image url would be available like this image.url. I have updated the code above to include the part of how to acccess the url.

Comment: Thanks a lot!It works like a charm! for the base64 image i've solved uploading every image to a single site(deviantArt) tnx again a lot!